# Why Mac (M1\M2) crashed while connecting to Win 7 PC via SMB

Tags: macos, crash, kernel

[image: connecting to server dialog image]

After choosing the guest option the system crashes and after the system restarts it gives the following logs to report, yes I've tried the Registered User option but that just not working.

```
Panic(cpu 2 caller 0xfffffe0018bf4840): kfree: addr 0xfffffe4454684000, size 444 (offs:0) not found in any zone @kalloc.c:2668 Debugger message: panic Memory ID: 0xff OS release type: User OS version: 23D60 Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version
23.3.0: Wed Dec 20 21:33:31 PST 2023; root:xnu-10002.81.5~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T8112 Fileset Kernelcache UUID: FEC775B3A6937256DD0F4754955B7AAF Kernel UUID: C7428EB0-BE7C-3056-8267-A75FED2CC4A4 Boot session UUID: 5DAC0FF5-04DA-4CC5-96FD-0144FD035DAF iBoot version: iBoot-10151.81.1 secure boot?: YES roots installed: 0 Paniclog version: 14 KernelCache slide: 0x000000000fe48000 KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0016e4c000 Kernel slide:      0x000000000fe50000 Kernel text base:  0xfffffe0016e54000 Kernel text exec slide: 0x00000000113a4000 Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe00183a8000 mach_absolute_time: 0x2c63da26f Epoch Time:        sec       usec   Boot    : 0x65d33f96 0x00094859   Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000   Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000   Calendar: 0x65d34181 0x000b9a0b

Zone info:   Zone map: 0xfffffe1a3a4ac000 - 0xfffffe3a3a4ac000   . VM  : 0xfffffe1a3a4ac000 - 0xfffffe1f07178000   . RO    : 0xfffffe1f07178000 - 0xfffffe20a0b10000   . GEN0  : 0xfffffe20a0b10000
- 0xfffffe256d7dc000   . GEN1  : 0xfffffe256d7dc000 - 0xfffffe2a3a4a8000   . GEN2  : 0xfffffe2a3a4a8000 - 0xfffffe2f07174000 . GEN3  : 0xfffffe2f07174000 - 0xfffffe33d3e40000   . DATA  : 0xfffffe33d3e40000 - 0xfffffe3a3a4ac000   Metadata: 0xfffffe101061c000
- 0xfffffe101861c000   Bitmaps : 0xfffffe101861c000 - 0xfffffe101b390000   Extra   : 0 - 0

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854c5a0 CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854c5a0 CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854ae00 CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854c5a0 CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854c5a0 CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854c5a0 CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854c5a0 CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001854c5a0 TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xfffffe2f067cb000  0: 0x0000000000000002  0ro: 0x000000016fbe70e0 } CORE 0 PVH locks held: None CORE 1 PVH locks held: None CORE 2 PVH locks held: None CORE 3 PVH locks held: None CORE 4 PVH locks held: None CORE 5 PVH locks held: None CORE 6 PVH locks held: None CORE 7 PVH locks held: None CORE 0: PC=0xfffffe0018473f34, LR=0xfffffe001840f648, FP=0xfffffe8e1bebb500 CORE 1: PC=0xfffffe0018542864, LR=0xfffffe0018541f64, FP=0xfffffe8e1c72ff10 CORE 2 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details. CORE 3: PC=0x00000001828f140c, LR=0x000000019b95cbe8, FP=0x000000016b8010e0 CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe001854732c, LR=0xfffffe0018547328, FP=0xfffffe8e1b4a7e80 CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe00184379c8, LR=0xfffffe00184379c8, FP=0xfffffe8e1c1f7ef0 CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe00184379cc, LR=0xfffffe00184379c8, FP=0xfffffe8e1c457ef0 CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe00184379cc, LR=0xfffffe00184379c8, FP=0xfffffe8e1c2b7ef0 Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space Panicked task 0xfffffe33d0ae1de8: 1123 pages, 7 threads: pid 1002: NetAuthSysAgent Panicked thread: 0xfffffe2f067cb000, backtrace: 0xfffffe8e1c4fee70, tid: 9568
          lr: 0xfffffe00183fe9a8  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4fef00
          lr: 0xfffffe001854382c  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4fef70
          lr: 0xfffffe0018541c98  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ff060
          lr: 0xfffffe00183af8cc  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ff070
          lr: 0xfffffe00183fe29c  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ff420
          lr: 0xfffffe0018bf1cc4  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ff440
          lr: 0xfffffe0018bf4840  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ff4c0
          lr: 0xfffffe001840fbe8  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ff500
          lr: 0xfffffe001b644b30  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ff9c0
          lr: 0xfffffe001861ae98  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ffa20
          lr: 0xfffffe001860cd30  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ffc40
          lr: 0xfffffe00188b2520  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ffc80
          lr: 0xfffffe0018918944  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ffd90
          lr: 0xfffffe0018a0ece0  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4ffe20
          lr: 0xfffffe0018541dc8  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4fff10
          lr: 0xfffffe00183af8cc  fp: 0xfffffe8e1c4fff20
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.smbfs(5.1)[C22A6A50-F264-363E-A2FA-98362C75B80C]@0xfffffe001b609ed0->0xfffffe001b6756d3
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(14.0)[1C9CBFB2-1EAF-3030-83D7-66135A0EDEC1]@0xfffffe001b4f7b00->0xfffffe001b54880b
            dependency: com.apple.kext.triggers(1.0)[2A33A36D-DCAA-3A3B-9241-C507139565FE]@0xfffffe001b67f620->0xfffffe001b681f2f

last started kext at 10893536652: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   5.1 (addr 0xfffffe0017898c70, size 82089) loaded kexts: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 5.1 com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0 com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1 com.apple.driver.CoreKDL  1 com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore    1 com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore    1 com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore    1 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0 com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage   493.0.0 com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0 com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0 com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0 com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP   4.0.3 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM    5.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1 com.apple.nke.l2tp    1.9 com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1 com.apple.filesystems.nfs 1 com.apple.filesystems.lifs    1 com.apple.filesystems.apfs    2235.80.4 com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily  1.0.0 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext    650.0.2 com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1 com.apple.BootCache   40 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib  1.0.0 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI 1 com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2    1 com.apple.driver.AppleSN012776Amp 700.46 com.apple.driver.ApplePMP    1 com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher    1 com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger 300.7 com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC   1 com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8112 300.15 com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial  1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleSerialShim    1 com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L84Audio    700.46 com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCRetimer   1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH14G-DCP  140.0 com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner   1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8112CLPC   1 com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware 1 com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptControllerV2   1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleProResHW  326.11.0 com.apple.AGXG14G  276.62 com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI   1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8112PMGR   1 com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO 1 com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2    703.54.1 com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver   6.2.2 com.apple.driver.AppleAVD 737.2 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule 1 com.apple.driver.AppleEventLogHandler 1 com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe 1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8110DART   1 com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C 1.0.0d2 com.apple.driver.AppleT8110 1 com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons  1.0.0d1 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI  1 com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility    1 com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity  1 com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2 273 com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 404 com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1 com.apple.kec.AppleEncryptedArchive   1 com.apple.driver.driverkit.serial 6.0.0 com.apple.plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin 1220.1 com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard    7400.2 com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice  1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio    610.3 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 500.4 com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver   100.99 com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily    1 com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl    1 com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI    1 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug  1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIPCI  1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI  1.2 com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager  1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory    1 com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer   1 com.apple.driver.AppleBTM 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.usb.networking   5.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   4.1.1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter   1.0.4 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  8.5.1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  8.5.1 com.apple.nke.ppp 1.9 com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0 com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy 1 com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter  3 com.apple.kext.triggers   1.0 com.apple.driver.IOHIDPowerSource   1 com.apple.driver.AppleCallbackPowerSource 1 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext  1 com.apple.driver.AppleSyntheticGameController 11.3.1 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI 1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI 1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub  1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU   1.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleSART    1 com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl    1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI    1.0.1 com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily  2.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly    1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess    1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio    300.14 com.apple.driver.AppleHPM    3.4.4 com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio 700.46 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio  700.46 com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio 300.11 com.apple.driver.AppleT8112TypeCPhy  1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy   1 com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP    343.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1 com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily    343.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0 com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0 com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1 com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit 1 com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG14GRTBuddy  1 com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64    276.62 com.apple.driver.AppleSPU    1 com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface 7.300.0 com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily   1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy    1 com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily   93.10.1 com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer  1 com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR    1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  7.2.81 com.apple.driver.AppleT8112PCIe  1 com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8112  800.11 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs  300.1 com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext  1 com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC  1 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   9.3.3 com.apple.iokit.IOPortFamily  1.0 com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1 com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager    1 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService   1 com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1200.13.0 com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader    1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL  1 com.apple.driver.corecapture  1.0.4 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE    1 com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily   1220.1 com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1230.2 com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController   1.0.2 com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler   1 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce   1 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    1230.2 com.apple.driver.DiskImages  493.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    598 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   9.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSSE 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM  556 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  243 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   492 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   492 com.apple.driver.AppleRSMChannel    1 com.apple.iokit.IORSMFamily   1 com.apple.driver.AppleLockdownMode    1 com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender  1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30 com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage   1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0 com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily   1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9 com.apple.driver.RTBuddy  1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor  1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU  1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial   1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1.0 com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily 1 com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP   1.0.2 com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor 1 com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor 2 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily   2.0.0 com.apple.AUC 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   352.0.3 com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily  1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily   1 com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family    1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleIISController 300.1 com.apple.driver.AppleAudioClockLibs  300.1 com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit    71.3.0 com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform    1.0.2 com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily  1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily    47 com.apple.security.quarantine    4 com.apple.security.sandbox    300.0 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   2.1 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5 com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily   1 com.apple.security.AppleImage4    5.0.0 com.apple.kext.CoreTrust  1 com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily 1.0.1 com.apple.kec.pthread 1 com.apple.kec.Libm    1 com.apple.kec.Compression 1.0 com.apple.kec.corecrypto    14.0



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 355899 (Uncompressed 882608) **
```

Comment: What kind of server is this? If you reboot both the Mac and the server and try again, does it still crash?

Comment: I am trying to connect to a local server that resides on windows 7 pc, I am able to access it easily using other windows machine but my Mac machine, I have tried this on two different Mac machine one is M1 and other is M2, and yes I have restarted them. Moreover, I can connect using my older Mac machine (Intel based chip) but when I tried to enter as a guest, it not not me the dialog to enter password to access that specific folder, unlike like windows that shows me the dialog for password.

Comment: Guest users don't need passwords (that's the main reason for having them)

Comment: What I am trying to say that there is no password on server but there is password on disk/folder/partition in windows. This will change the topic, I will explain that later, the main issue is why the Mac with Apple Silicon chip is crashing.

Comment: Ah. Not sure if access to folders which are password-protected on WIndows side is even possible over Samba.

Comment: So sorry, I meant the drive